# Unable to start Groovy Spring Boot project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, groovy, spring-tool-suite

Here's an odd one. I have a Spring Boot app, that uses Groovy and Web starters. If I run `mvn spring-boot:run` it starts fine, and if I run `mvn package` and then `java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` it also runs fine.  But if I choose `Run As -> Spring Boot Application` I get this error:

```
12:16:22.200 ERROR [Tomcat-startStop-1   ] [ContainerBase] [] A child 
container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
12:16:22.201 ERROR [main                 ] [ContainerBase] [] A child container failed during start
```

In Eclipe's POM editor I don't see the `javax.servlet-api.jar` file being brought in, so I added it, but no effect.

Eclipse: Oxygen 4.7.1a

STS: 3.9.1.201710100539-RELEASE

Java: 1.8.0_151

POM is straight from start.spring.io:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha!  I had to remove the "Groovy Libraries" and "Groovy DSL Support" from the Java Build Path in Eclipse - they were bringing in a `servlet-api-2.4.jar` file.

Comment: You can also enable the minimal attribute on Groovy Libraries and it will not include servlet-api.jar any more but you will still get groovy-all.jar on your project's classpath.